# OpenGL VS2008 on C++: Same code bevahes differently even on the same computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opengl, glut

I have two exact same codes OpenGL C++ , compiled using VS2008 in different project , but when i compile them, it behaves differently. One of them can recognize  the condition `if ( mod == GLUT_ACTIVE_CTRL && button == GLUT_WHEEL_UP )` and one of them is not.

Here is the complete function:

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {

int mod = glutGetModifiers();
mouseState = state;
mouseButton = button;
double modelview[16], projection[16];

int viewport[4];
float z = 0 ;

/*Read the projection, modelview and viewport matrices
using the glGet functions.*/
glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, viewport );
glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );
//glGetDoublev( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection );

//Read the window z value from the z-buffer 
glReadPixels( x, viewport[3]-y, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &z );   

// Used for wheels, has to be up    
if (state == GLUT_UP )  {       
    if ( mod == GLUT_ACTIVE_CTRL && button == GLUT_WHEEL_UP ){                  
        printf("Wheel Up\n");
        zoom += 0.1;
    }
    else if (mod == GLUT_ACTIVE_CTRL &&  button == GLUT_WHEEL_DOWN ){
        printf("Wheel Down\n"); 
        zoom -= 0.1;
    }


    else if (mod == GLUT_ACTIVE_ALT && button == GLUT_WHEEL_UP) {
        //printf("Z++\n");
        translation_z = translation_z + 0.1;
        //printf("Z = %f", translation_z);
    }

    else if (mod == GLUT_ACTIVE_ALT && button == GLUT_WHEEL_DOWN) {
        //printf("Z--\n");
        translation_z = translation_z - 0.1;
    }

    else if (mod == GLUT_ACTIVE_SHIFT && button == GLUT_WHEEL_UP) {
        //printf("Shift Wheel Up. Z axis rotation goes here.\n");
        zrotation += (5*(z - oldZ)); // about x-axis
    }

    else if (mod == GLUT_ACTIVE_SHIFT && button == GLUT_WHEEL_DOWN) {
        //printf("Shift Wheel Down. Z Axis rotation goes here\n");
        zrotation -= (5*(z - oldZ)); // about x-axis
        //translation_z = translation_z - 0.1;
    }


}
else if (state == GLUT_DOWN) {
    //printf("Glut Down before z processing\n");

    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON){
        cursorX = x;
        cursorY = y;
        mode = SELECT;
        //printf("Left is down\n");
    }

    oldX = x;
    oldY = y;
}
}
```

`

and I uploaded both of the [project here](http://www.4shared.com/file/M_YZjMOv/Projects.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, In the project that can not recognize wheel up/down condition (despite that it should), I included:

freeglut.lib glut32.lib opengl32.lib user32.lib

This can be solved by including only the following libs:

opengl32.lib user32.lib

Thank you @melak47 for suggesting to check the project settings.

Answer (score 2):

Both the source and the project settings appear to be exactly the same.
I can't see any added include paths though, do you have a copy of opengl locally in both projects?

Only other thing I can think of right now is this comment from your source...

```cpp
//Use patched version of GLUT (http://www.realmtech.net/opengl/glut.php) in case the wheel interaction does not work.
```

1) This sounds like it might relate to the exact problem you are having.

2) Did you maybe use that patched version in one project, but not the other?

Edit:
In one of the projects you have the printf lines for wheel down and wheel up commented out, is this by any chance how you tell that one doesn't recognize the wheel?

Comment: So i guess the reason was an instability of the patched version of freeglut? I use the same patched version of freeglut for both project. Yes, thats how I recognize the wheel.